# Clear queue for sideDown jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I have problem with this code, multiple animation effects run with each other.
When I move mouse on navbarli1, then on another li that has navbarli1 class, the li isn't slide down anymore.

HTML

```
<li class="navbarli1">
   <div class="liHover">
      <a href="" title="">آموزش</a>
      <div class="SubMenu">
         <ul class="ulsubmenu">
            <li>کلاس های حضوری</li>
            <li>کلاس های غیر حضوری</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</li>
<li class="navbarli1">
   <div class="liHover">
      <a href="" title="">فروش تجهیزات</a>
      <div class="SubMenu">
         <ul class="ulsubmenu">
            <li>سخت افزاری</li>
            <li>نرم افزاری</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</li>
```

jQuery for animation

```
$(".navbarli1").mouseover(function () {
    $(".ulsubmenu", this).stop().slideDown("medium");
});
$(".navbarli1").mouseout(function () {
    $(".ulsubmenu", this).stop().slideUp("medium");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Wtkcb/)?

This is the code I have:

```
$(".navbarli1").mouseover(function () {
    $(this).find(".ulsubmenu").eq(0).stop().slideToggle();
});
$(".navbarli1").mouseout(function () {
    $(this).find(".ulsubmenu").eq(0).stop().slideToggle();
});
```

What it does is it finds the `.ulsubmenu`'s. The `eq[0]` takes the first one it finds. I used slideToggle but you could use `.slideUp()` and `.slideDown()` as well.